# Allocating C-style string on the Heap

Tags: c++

guys, I need a little technical help.
I'm working in C++, don't have much experience working in it but know the language somewhat. I need to use a C-style string (char array) but I need to allocate it on the heap.

If you look at this very simple piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char* getText()
{
    return "Hello";
}

int main()
{
    char* text;
    text = getText();
    cout << text;
    //delete text; // Calling delete results in an error
}
```

Now, I'm assuming that the "Hello" string is allocated on the stack, within getText(), which means the pointer will be "floating" as soon as getText returns, am I right?

If I'm right, then what's the best way to put "Hello" on the heap so I can use that string outside of getText and call delete on the pointer if I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `std::string`, from the `<string>` header. Then use its `.c_str()` member function. Then you don't have to care about allocation and deallocation: it takes care of it for you, correctly.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: agreed. this is the C++ way. you should not be thinking of C techniques in C++.

Comment: Sounds like the best solution. I only need to be able to return a pointer to the string. Thanks everybody who replied :)

Answer (score 6):

No, there's no hidden stack allocation going on there. `"Hello"` is static data, and ends up in the [.data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) of your program.

This also means the string is shared for all calls to `getText`. A common use when this would be acceptable is if you have a large list of error messages that map to error codes. Functions like `strerror` work like this, so that you can get descriptive error messages for standard library error codes. But nobody is supposed to modify the return value of `strerror` (also because it is `const`). In your case, your function definition should read:

```
const char *getText()
```

If you do want a private copy of the string returned, you can use the `strdup` function to make a copy:

```
return strdup("Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not right. "Hello" is a static string constant and it really should be const char*.

Answer (score 0):

> **A narrow string literal** has type "array of *n* `const char`", where *n* is the size of the string as defined below, and **has static storage duration**.

*Static storage* is neither *automatic* ("on the stack") nor *dynamic* ("on the heap"). It is allocated prior to the actual runtime of your program, so pointers to string literals never become invalid.

Note that `char* p = "Hello"` is deprecated because it is dangerous: the type system cannot prevent you from trying to change the string literal through `p` (which would result in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/)). Use `const char* p = "Hello"` instead.